# Duplicate rows when attempting a 5 table join

Tags: sql, sqlite

**Background:** First post so go easy on me! ;-) I'm having some problems with a SQLite join across 5 tables. I'm building a watering system on my Raspberry Pi, using Python, with the following table structure built in SQLite:

**deviceTable** - table lists all watering devices

**programTable** - table listing all watering programs

**zoneTable** - table listing all watering zones

**assignProgramTable** - bridging table for assigning many watering program to many zones

**assignDeviceTable** - bridging table for assigning many devices to many watering zones.

**Problem:** I'm currently using the following query to try and join all of these tables together so that I can begin to control my Raspberry Pi with a multi-threaded Python script... I originally had this working as a nested SQL script (working dynamically in my Python script), but it got a little complex when trying to run multiple thread within a database results. Essentially I plan to take a number of key values from the SQL query and

There appears to be multiple rows  being returned when there should only be one for each entry.. any idea of the best way to handle this? I've found a number of answers suggesting to use the DISTINCT option (which didn't work), although am I going about this the best way possible?

```
SELECT * 
FROM deviceTable AS d, programTable AS p 
JOIN assignDeviceTable AS ad ON d.deviceID = ad.deviceID 
JOIN zoneTable AS z ON z.zoneID = a.zoneID 
JOIN assignProgramTable AS a ON p.programID = a.programID 
where p.programStatus = "1"
```

Following LS_dev's advice, I've updated the query to the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM deviceTable AS d, programTable AS p, assignDeviceTable AS ad, zoneTable AS z, assignProgramTable AS ap 
JOIN deviceTable ON d.deviceID = ad.deviceID
JOIN assignDeviceTable ON ad.zoneID = z.zoneID 
JOIN zoneTable ON z.zoneID = ap.zoneID 
JOIN assignProgramTable ON ap.programID = p.programID  
where p.programStatus = "1"
```

Unfortunately this resulted in even more rows being duplicated... still stuck!

Comment: can your provide data from your tables?

Comment: You are missing relation between `deviceTable AS d` and `programTable AS p`!

Comment: Tried following this advice with the updated SQL (above)... produced even more duplicate rows!

Comment: You didn't add any relation (join constraint: `ON ...`)!!! You just joined more tables in same query! `,` has same meanig as `JOIN` in SQLite!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLite `,` is same as `JOIN`.

So, your query is same as shown below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM deviceTable AS d
JOIN programTable AS p  -- missing ON p.some_id=d.some_id
JOIN assignDeviceTable AS ad ON d.deviceID = ad.deviceID 
JOIN zoneTable AS z ON z.zoneID = a.zoneID 
JOIN assignProgramTable AS a ON p.programID = a.programID 
where p.programStatus = "1"
```

You have 5 tables but just 3 join constraints. Normally `Nconstraints = Ntables - 1`.

Analysing your relations:

```
       programTable p                    deviceTable d
           / \                               / \
(p.programID=a.programID)          (d.deviceID=ad.deviceID)
           \ /                               \ /
    assignProgramTable a             assignDeviceTable ad
           / \
   (z.zoneID=a.zoneID)
           \ /
        zoneTable z
```

is visible your missing a relation between those two groups. From your explanation I think it should be something like `ad.zoneID = z.zoneID`.

Comment: Got it working with the advice above... as advised, was missing the final constraint. Thanks so much for your help!